# How to make surround commands repeatable in ideavim?

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I am using ideavim plugin in Pycharm. I tried deleting surrounding braces with `dsb` and when i try to repeat it with dot `.`it doesn't repeat. How can I make it repeatable ?

Answer (score 1):

The short version is: it's impossible without additional tooling.

Even the original vim-surround plugin for Vim requires an extra plugin to handle the surround action for the extra commands offered by vim-surround. Please show your interest in this feature by voting for https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/pull/110 or by contributing your code or by helping to test this PR.